3D mapping kit doesn't keep room structure
I’m building a 3d mapping kit with a 2D lidar M2M2 Mapper and a D435i realsense camera and I’m getting close to succeeding.
I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 with ros noetic. All dependecies, drivers, SDK are installed. I’m also working with RTABMAP and Rviz.
I would like to have your feed back on this:

This is one of my first successful capture on RTABMAP. As you can see, I’m having issues keeping the actual structure of the room I’m scanning.
What am I doing wrong here? Would you say this is an odometry problem? Synchronization? IMU? I don’t know.
I’m using the rtabmap.launch default file but modified it (it’s 500 lines long).
Here is my RQT TF tree, seems to be working (for the most part). I am no programmer by the way!

Thank you all!
PEACE!
